# Constant is undefined in a service but works in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, constants

I have a silly problem with angular. I have a constant defined for my app. And I inject it in 2 different services `Auth` and `Profile`. In `Auth`, it works like a charm. In `Profile, it's undefined. Can't see what I'm missing here.

`auth.service.js` :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App')
    .factory('AuthService', AuthService);

    AuthService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'API_URL'];

    function AuthService($http, $q, $window, API_URL) {
        //API_URL works
    }
})();
```

`profile.service.js` :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App')
    .factory('ProfileService', ProfileService);

    ProfileService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'API_URL'];

    function ProfileService($http, $q, $window, API_URL) {
        //API_URL is undefined
    }
})();
```

`app.constants.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App')
    .constant('API_URL','/api/v1/');
})();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProfileService` function does not have window injected, either remove it or add it,

```
ProfileService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'API_URL'];
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^

function ProfileService($http, $q, $window, API_URL) {

}
```

Comment: Now I can hang myself. Thanks.